# Array () does not match expected type "object"

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to write test cod for function in repository.My repo code is;

```
 public function getcomment($id){

    $data = ProductComment::active()
        ->where('productId',$id)
        ->orderBy('date','desc')
        ->simplePaginate(5)->items();
    return $data;
}
```

for this I wrote this test code;

```
 public function testgetcomment(){
    /*$Mock = \Mockery::mock(Product::class);
    $Mock->shouldReceive('getId')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);
    $this->repo->getcomment($Mock->getId());
    $this->assertTrue(true);*/

    $ecpected=ProductComment::where('productId',1)->get(); 

    $actual=$this->repo->getcomment(1); 

    self::assertEquals($expected,$actual);}
```

I am getting this error;

Array () does not match expected type "object". Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Check your variables names (`$ecpected` contains data you are pulling from Model, and `$expected` is the one you are trying to compare).

```
$ecpected=ProductComment::where('productId',1)->get(); 
$actual=$this->repo->getcomment(1); 
self::assertEquals($expected,$actual);
```

2.You can check dumps for both variables in comparison (to be sure that you are getting different type (Your repo returns an Array, while querying ProductComment returning you an Object/collection.).

```
dump($expected);
dump($actual);
```

3. You probably need to use `toArray()` method on your `$expected` variable to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2):

The [`items()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html#method_items) function on a pagination object returns an array of objects. However, the [`get()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get) function on Eloquent queries returns a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections) of objects.

To fix your test, return the underlying array from the collection.

```
$ecpected = ProductComment::where('productId',1)->get()->toArray(); 
$actual = $this->repo->getcomment(1); 
self::assertEquals($expected,$actual);
```